# How to connect form with reCaptcha to Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, recaptcha

I have a form set up to connect its responses to a Google spreadsheet, but it is of late getting some spam, all of a very similar type. I cannot pin down the IP addresses like I usually do, to exclude them from the site, so I am trying to institute Google reCaptcha.

The submit button for the form as it is without reCaptcha is this code:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send me the magazine" id="ss-submit" class="jfk-button jfk-button-action ">
```

The reCaptcha instructions say to use this for your button:

> "Paste this snippet at the end of the <form> to create a button protected by reCAPTCHA. You will need to create a callback function to handle the result."

```
<button class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="SiteKeyHere" data-callback="YourOnSubmitFn">Submit</button>
```

I am not sure how to integrate the two buttons, if it is possible. I don't know what to do to "create a callback function to handle the result" as mentioned in the reCaptcha instructions. If you please could help me to understand this, I would be grateful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Physically you can't. The office standard just won't have this enabled.
As far as I know reCaptcha only works on php type sites, not in an office file.
You can however set your spreadsheet to invite only.

Comment: Thank you. To clarify, in case it makes a difference: this is a website form that is connected to Google sheets, not an Office file. The form is a Google form that is embedded in the website (on a php page), and the responses are sent to the sheet, and then emailed out to recipients.

Comment: Will check it out. Thank you.